# CGAffineTransform changes view.bounds?

Tags: ios, frame, cgaffinetransform, bounds

> Views have both a frame (coordinates in superview's coordinate system)
>   and bounds (coordinates in own coordinate system) property, but if you
>   transform a view, you should not use or rely on the frame property
>   anymore. If you are using transformations, work with the bounds
>   property only, not the frame property, as transformations are applied
>   to the bounds, but aren't necessarily reflected accurately in frame

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.jp/2008/10/demystifying-cgaffinetransform.html

I wanted to see what he means in the above paragraph and printed 'frame' and 'bounds'
And I see only 'frame' is changing during the pinch.

```
- (IBAction)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"scale: %f, velocity: %f", recognizer.scale, recognizer.velocity);
    NSLog(@"Before, frame: %@, bounds: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(recognizer.view.frame), NSStringFromCGRect(recognizer.view.bounds));
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    NSLog(@"After, frame: %@, bounds: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(recognizer.view.frame), NSStringFromCGRect(recognizer.view.bounds));

    recognizer.scale = 1;
}
```

output:(zomming in)

```
2012-07-02 14:53:51.458 GestureRec[1264:707] scale: 1.030111, velocity: 0.945660
2012-07-02 14:53:51.466 GestureRec[1264:707] Before, frame: {{0, 124}, {320, 160}}, bounds: {{0, 0}, {320, 160}}
2012-07-02 14:53:51.473 GestureRec[1264:707] After, frame: {{-4.81771, 121.591}, {329.635, 164.818}}, bounds: {{0, 0}, {320, 160}}
2012-07-02 14:53:51.480 GestureRec[1264:707] scale: 1.074539, velocity: 1.889658
2012-07-02 14:53:51.484 GestureRec[1264:707] Before, frame: {{-4.81771, 121.591}, {329.635, 164.818}}, bounds: {{0, 0}, {320, 160}}
2012-07-02 14:53:51.494 GestureRec[1264:707] After, frame: {{-17.103, 115.449}, {354.206, 177.103}}, bounds: {{0, 0}, {320, 160}}
2012-07-02 14:53:51.499 GestureRec[1264:707] scale: 1.000000, velocity: 1.889658
2012-07-02 14:53:51.506 GestureRec[1264:707] Before, frame: {{-17.103, 115.449}, {354.206, 177.103}}, bounds: {{0, 0}, {320, 160}}
2012-07-02 14:53:51.510 GestureRec[1264:707] After, frame: {{-17.103, 115.449}, {354.206, 177.103}}, bounds: {{0, 0}, {320, 160}}
```

Am I misunderstanding something or the author in the blog is wrong?

Comment: Can you log both values before and after the transform, and log the scale value you are using as well? And actually include the output in your question :)

Answer (score 8):

I think I've got it:

The blog is correct, according even to [Apple themselves](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Coordinates/Coordinates.html):

> To translate or scale the coordinate system, you alter the view's
>   bounds rectangle...

However bounds doesn't change because the rectangle itself is still the same size you've reported it, only the coordinate system has scaled with it.  You see:

> Changing the bounds rectangle sets up the basic coordinate system with
>   which all drawing performed by the view begins.

and because we never explicitly change bounds, only the view's frame relative to its superview changes.

In fact, I can mathematically prove the bounds never change!  Here, run this sample instead:

```
NSLog(@"scale: %f, velocity: %f", recognizer.scale, recognizer.velocity);
    NSLog(@"Before, frame: %@, bounds: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(recognizer.view.frame), NSStringFromCGRect(recognizer.view.bounds));
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    NSLog(@"After, frame: %@, bounds: %@ transform:%@", NSStringFromCGRect(recognizer.view.frame), NSStringFromCGRect(recognizer.view.bounds), NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(recognizer.view.transform));

    recognizer.scale = 1;
```

Now, if you notice, the values reported from `NSStringFromCGAffineTransform()` multiplied by the bounds is equivalent to the view's frame.  But what about what the blog said?  Not *necessarily* accurate is right.  Transformation matrices can apply to more than just the x and y of this thing, if we really wanted to, we could transform z values and rotate, and flip, and every which way, all of these change the frame property in non-linear ways, especially when used in tandom.

An interesting conundrum, if I do say so myself.