# UIKit Why bounds won't change when scale transform is applied

Tags: ios, uikit

I wanted to really get into the differences between view's bounds and frame. I understand that frame is relative to the view's superview and bounds are relative to the view itself. I also understand that if for example I rotate a view, the bounds won't change but that frame will. 
I saw this answer and it helped me a lot: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28917673/3927046

**I ran into a case which got me confused again**. I transformed an image scale and printed the frame's and the bound's width and height. The frame changed but the bounds didn't!
I saw this answer about this case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11288488/3927046

But it still unclear. Why bound won't change when scaling a view? When applied to the logic of the first link's answer, the width an the height need to be changed too...

I'm confused ): Any help?

Thanks!